# worker is getting restarted continuously with closedchannel exception in supervisor

Tags: apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

worker which is in one of the supervisor is getting restarted continuously and getting Closedchannel exception .  But if run the same topology in another storm cluster which is in another environment , it is running without giving any errors.

### Below is the error i can see from Storm UI.

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException at org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:103) at org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.getMyManagedPartitions(ZkCoordinator.java:69) at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:129) at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__7990$fn__8005$fn__8036.invoke(executor.clj:648) at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:484) at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:78) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:68) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:127) at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:79) at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:75) at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:65) at org.apache.storm.kafka.PartitionManager.(PartitionManager.java:94) at org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:98) ... 6 mo

Can any one please help me to find out the exact issue.Please let me know if need any more information.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and problem was that ZooKeeper host names not being resolved from worker host.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you have concrete steps the OP can take to resolve the issue, provide them. If this issue is unsolvable n the current context, explain why/.